# finding an element in an array based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hi new to python and programming in general
 I'm trying to find an element in an array based on user input 
here's what i've done

```
a =[31,41,59,26,41,58]
input = input("Enter number : ")
for i in range(1,len(a),1) :
    if input == a[i] :
       print(i)
```

problem is that it doesn't print out anything.
what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` returns a string. To make them integers wrap them in `int`.

```
inp=int(input('enter :'))
for i in range(0,len(a)-1): 
    if inp==a[i]:
        print(i)
```

Indices in `list` start from *0* to *len(list)-1*.

Instead of using `range(0,len(a)-1)` it's preferred to use `enumerate`.

```
for idx,val in enumerate(a):
    if inp==val:
        print(idx)
```

---

To check if a `inp` is in `a` you can this.

```
>>> inp in a
True #if it exists or else False
```

---

You can use `try-except` also.

```
try:
    print(a.index(inp))
except ValueError:
    print('Element not Found')
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string; `a` contains integers.

Your loop starts at 1, so it will never test against `a[0]` (in this case, 31).

And you shouldn't re-define the name `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't declare a variable ***input*** is not a good practise and ***Space*** is very important in Python

```
a =[31,41,59,26,41,58]
b = input("Enter number : ")
for i in range(1,len(a),1):
    if int(b) == a[i] :
        print(i)
```

I think you want to check a value from your list so your input need to be a ***Int***. But input takes it as String. That's you need to convert it into int.

Answer (score 0):

input is providing you a str but you are comparing a list of ints. That and your loop starts at 1 but your index starts at 0